How can I output a selection of Blog objects in a ListView in Django searched via ForeignKeys of two other different models?
I have three models like this:
1:
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    published = models.DateField()
    ...

2:
class AuthorList(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    lastTimeEdited = models.DateTimeField()
    ...

3:
class CommentsList(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    commentAuthor = models.ForeignKey(User)
    commentPosted = models.DateTimeField()
    ...

My class based ListView looks like this:
class DashboardView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'app/dashboard.html'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self) -> QuerySet[Blog]:
        user = self.request.user
        author = #HERE I want a queryset of all blogs, where the requested user is one of the authors.
        commentator = #HERE I want a queryset of all blogs, where the requested user is one of the commentators.
        blogs = author|commentator
        return blogs.order_by(#HERE I want to order them by the lastTimeEdited-Field or the commentPosted-Field)

So I want to list all the blogs that the user has to do with in one way or another. I also want to order them by the lastTimeEdited value if the user is an author or by the commentPosted value if the user is a commenter. How can I do that?
I've already looked for the solution in other posts, but couldn't find the right solution for my problem.

What would the ordering be if the same Blog object has both hits in the comment and author, or multiple comments/authors?

Then it should chose the lastTimeEdited Field

Your AuthorList model acts as a junction table for a many-to-many relation between Blog and User. You can span a ManyToManyField [Django-doc] on the Blog model with:
class Blog(models.Model):
    # …
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        through='AuthorList',
        related_name='authored_blogs',
    )
    commenters = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        through='CommentsList',
        related_name='commented_blogs',
    )
This makes querying a lot easier, since we can work with:
from django.db.models import Q


class DashboardView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'app/dashboard.html'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self) -> QuerySet[Blog]:
        return Blog.objects.filter(
            Q(authors=request.user) | Q(commenters=request.user)
        ).order_by(???)
The only problem now is how to order, we can determine the last author and/or comment time with .annotate(…) [Django-doc] and then use this:
from django.db.models import Greatest, Max, Q


class DashboardView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'app/dashboard.html'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self) -> QuerySet[Blog]:
        return (
            Blog.objects.filter(
                Q(authors=request.user) | Q(commenters=request.user)
            )
            .annotate(
                latest_edit=Greatest(
                    Max('authorlist__lastTimeEdited'),
                    Max('commentslist__lastTimeEdited'),
                )
            )
            .order_by('-latest_edit')
        )
For databases like SQLite, Oracle and MySQL, this will not be sufficient, since if there the user is not an author, or a commenter, it will return NULL, only if you are both author and commenter, that will work. We can fix this in a very ugly way with Coalesce [Django-doc]:
from django.db.models import Coalesce, Greatest, Max, Q


class DashboardView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'app/dashboard.html'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self) -> QuerySet[Blog]:
        return (
            Blog.objects.filter(
                Q(authors=request.user) | Q(commenters=request.user)
            )
            .annotate(
                latest_edit=Greatest(
                    Coalesce(
                        Max('authorlist__lastTimeEdited'),
                        Max('commentslist__lastTimeEdited'),
                    ),
                    Coalesce(
                        Max('commentslist__lastTimeEdited'),
                        Max('authorlist__lastTimeEdited'),
                    ),
                )
            )
            .order_by('-latest_edit')
        )


Note: It is normally better to make use of the settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL [Django-doc] to refer to the user model, than to use the User model [Django-doc] directly. For more information you can see the referencing the User model section of the documentation [Django-doc].


Let's say it's impossible for you to be both an author and a commenter on a blog. Would anything change then?

@mr.xy: no, we only look if you are, or an author, or a commentator.

Why is the fix with Coalesce very ugly?

@mr.xy: because we calculate the items twice.
